# uncompact time in Rindler vacuum

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

This is a very basic question I encountered in the class.

Consider the spacetime near a black hole's horizon. Go to the Euclidean spacetime and ignore S^2 portion of the space. 
In Rindler spacetime,
$$ds^2 = dX^2+dT_E^2 = \rho^2d\theta^2 + d\rho^2.$$
The lecturer said that in the polar coordinate (RHS), the identification of $\theta \sim \theta + 2\pi$ can only avoid the conic singularity.
Then he mentioned that the time coordinate is now $\textit{uncompact}$ with the identification.

But, as far as I know, $[0,2\pi]$ is compact under the topology with open intervals. Doesn't this mean that the coordinate time 't' is compact?

Also, what is the difference between Minkwoski vacuum and the Rindler vacuum?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> But, as far as I know, $[0,2\pi]$ is compact under the topology with open intervals. Doesn't this mean that the coordinate time 't' is compact?

I confused $[0,2\pi)$ with $[0,2\pi]$.  Recognizing that the half-open interval is not compact answers my question.

Comment: I edited your answer to be more answer-like, such that now it's an actual answer to your question (since this was in the "_low quality posts_" review queue).  However, because there aren't any other answers yet, you may have the option of deleting the question, which could make sense if you no longer want feedback from others.

Comment: Thanks @Nat. I was struggling finding how to delet thr post.